# Mudar palavra em frase de acordo com dicionário

Tags: python, dicionário

Tem um exercício que consiste em  digitar um número N e em seguida digitar em N linhas uma palavra e uma qualidade. Após isto devo digitar uma frase. Se nesta frase existir uma palavra que eu tinha digitado antes, deve-se imprimir sua respectiva qualidade. Exemplo

ENTRADA

> ```
> 3
> boldo explosiva
> tampa chorosa
> beijo calorosa
> Vocˆe pˆos a tampa no boldo ?
> ```

Saída

> ```
> chorosa explosiva
> ```

Meu código é esse aqui mas não dá certo.

```
dic={}
lista=[]

n=int(input()) 
for i in range(n):
    dic["palavra"],dic["adjetivo"]=input().split()

    lista.append(dic.copy())
frase=input()

for i in frase:
    if i in dic["palavra"]:
        print(dic["adjetivo"])
```

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 2):

Acho que é isto que você deseja, pelo menos dá o resultado determinado:

```
dic = {}
n = int(input()) 
for i in range(n):
    palavra, adjetivo = input().split()
    dic[palavra] = adjetivo
frase = input().split()
for palavra in frase:
    if palavra in dic:
        print(dic[palavra])
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/9MvU8j). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/kxujqwon-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Collection/ChangeInDict.py).

O que está criando é um dicionário natural, não é para criar dois deles, uma coluna é a chave do dicionário e a outra coluna é o valor, isto já simplifica o código porque nem precisa de lista alguma. A seleção da frase não faz muito sentido. Eu mandei verificar se a palavra está disponível em todo o dicionário, o seu código só olhava um item dele (na verdade o único) e aí pega-se o valor do item de acordo com a chave (a palavra sendo verificada) que você já sabe que existe. Troquei o nome da variável para algo mais significativo. E fiz um `split()` na frase também, para separar as palavras, não estava fazendo isto.